# wpa_supplicant runs only once after the raspberry boots

Tags: pi-3, wifi, wpa, fullapgeos

I have a raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

I have installed [fullpageos](https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS) on the rasp.

I run the `wpa_supplicant` command to connect to the wifi. I use the following command -

```
wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -cconfig.conf -B
```

The config file looks like the following -

```
network=
{
    ssid="my_ssid"
    psk="my_password"
}
```

The command works only once after a reboot. When I want to change the wifi network (with an edit in the config file), the command gives the error `4 way handshake failed, pre shared key may be wrong`, where as the key for the wifi network is correct.

This looks bizarre because it works the first time. I hope I am not missing anything important.

Comment: You would have to explain what networking system it uses. There are only 2 posts with this tag (the other by the author) - frankly the fact that he didn't get the name right in the tag, and also misspells the name (diferently) in his post, doesn't exactly inspire confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

> ```
> sudo ifdown wlan0
> sudo ifup wlan0
> ```

once you modify the `wpa_supplicant` file.